Excel date values acting like text
I am trying to clean all the cells in a column to have the Date format (specifically format of March 14, 2012, as previewed in Format options). I would like to show the first three letters of Column D using the LEFT function.
When I try to use the LEFT function on column D, all the values yield the date serial number, so column D is still formatting as Text?
Column J is the output of =TRIM(D#), showing Date serial numbers.
Column K is the output of =ISTEXT(D#), showing FALSE for column D, other than the top line.
Column L is the output of =LEFT(D#, 3), showing first 3 characters of date serial numbers.
In the Excel forum, someone advised me to use Visual Basic Editor and enter line Value.Selection = Value.Selection, then press Enter. I tried that twice, once with saving the Excel sheet and then returning to it, and once while going straight from VBE to Excel. Excel is still converting the date values to serial date values, even though Column D is meant to be in Date format.
Edit: Not able to add an image unfortunately, due to being new on stack overflow.

Can you add a screenshot of what you have now and what you expect? (TRIM and LEFT are text functions, so they return text strings, even if they appear to be numbers. You can add -- in front to force conversion to number: =--LEFT() =--TRIM() )

The cell format does not change the underlying value.  It just displays it differently.  I think you want =TEXT(D#,"MMM")  That would return MAR from the date shown above.

To Excel Dates are numbers.  Changing the Cell Format does not change the underlying value.  It may show March 14, 2012 but the underlying value is 40982.
So using LEFT or TRIM will only look at the number and not the displayed value.
To get the Month use TEXT:
=TEXT(D#,"MMM")

This will change the number to a string in the format desired.
